# Camera motion tracking: "Unable to reconstruct" due to "POINT BEHIND CAMERA 1"

Tags: tracking

I am doing a very simple camera motion tracking, and I almost always get the errors:

```
E1227 07:10:20.242158  6528 intersect.cc:159] POINT BEHIND CAMERA 1: 01.12694e+07 00000-502884 -2.22473e+07
E1227 07:10:20.244158  6528 intersect.cc:159] POINT BEHIND CAMERA 1: 01.12479e+07 -1.40083e+06 -1.93429e+07
E1227 07:10:20.246158  6528 intersect.cc:159] POINT BEHIND CAMERA 1: 016253.3 -19688.9 -87439.6
Unable to reconstruct position for track #2 'Track.002'
Unable to reconstruct position for track #3 'Track.003'
Unable to reconstruct position for track #4 'Track.004'
```

like this:

[image]

The video is simple; little movement and all the tracking points are visible from start to end. Only 8 points so far, I wanted to keep it simple to understand the errors above somehow.

First frame:

[image]

Half way:

[image]

Last frame:

[image]

The blue/red lines all look good to me; none loose track, they keep on point.

If I check the "Tripod" on the Solve tab, it works, but I get a huge error (Solve error: 11.62 px), which also is very odd to me.

*If I now change the "Sensor width" to 16.000 and "Focal length" to 17.00 (which is what I think that the Huawei P30 has), then the error just disappears, but I still get a solve error of 13.79.*

- Changing "Sensor width" and "focal length" resolves this error? But why? Im not even sure that the numbers I entered are correct.

Comment: The linked answer _does not answer my question_ or in any other way resolve it. I have looked at that specific question before I posted here, like I have many others.